# Locally installed Google Web fonts appear blurred in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-webfonts

I recently started using the Open Sans Google webfont for my website. Things went well until I installed the Open Sans font onto my computer in the local font dir (Windows XP). Then all of a sudden and only on my computer and in Firefox and Chrome (latest versions running on Windows XP) the Open Sans font started to appear blurred. I thought it had something to do with my site but looking at the Google Web font site, that particular font looked blurred too. Strangely enough IE8 did not suffer from this problem.
I removed the Open Sans font from my Windows font directory and the fonts became crystal clear again on my computer and in all browsers. 
Is there a way to keep the Open Sans font installed on my PC (easy if you want to create mockups using that font,....) without ending up with a blurred font in FF and Chrome for any site using Open Sans?

Comment: Hey Pete, I've just discovered this exact same problem (on Windows 7) - did you find out any more about a/the solution? Is very annoying! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and fixed it by install Microsoft's Cleartype tuning.
Had to install the [powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypePowerToy.mspx) as the web version wouldn't work for me